# Глагол на букву "а"

Tags: этимология

Есть ли в русском языке незаимствованный глагол, начинающийся с буквы  "а"?

Comment: Не_заимствованный: слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 4):

Пожалуйста, незаимствованный:

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x)

**АРТАЧИТЬСЯ**, -чусь, -чишься; ***нсв. (св.* заартачиться) 1.**  Не повиноваться кучеру, наезднику, пастуху (о лошади, корове и т.п.). **2.** *Разг.* Не соглашаться, упрямиться (о человеке). *Зря артачишься! Пойдём, хватит а.*